# RewriteEngine and category link

Tags: .htaccess

i'm trying to do something like

```
business/index.html
business/
business
```

to open `categories.php?prefix=$1`

i'm used

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?(index.html)?$ categories.php?prefix=$1 [QSA,L]
```

its worked great, but when open /admin its a real folder, its read it as a category
how i can exclude that

Comment: Do you need this for `admin` only, or for all existing folders? If latter, prepend that rule with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line.

Comment: @raina77ow give me the code please

Comment: What do you mean? It _is_ the code. Add that line with `RewriteCond` right before the line with `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look to see if the path starts with either `admin` or `images`. If it does, the rule will not apply. If it doesn't (i.e. if it starts with anything else), the rule will apply:

```
# Only apply to files that exist (uncomment to use):
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# Only apply if the request is NOT for a directory (uncomment to use):
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Only apply when the requested URI begins with admin or images (Not Case-sensitive):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/[admin|images]/) [NC]
# If all conditions are met, apply the following rule:
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?(index.html)?$ categories.php?prefix=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: and if i want to add more? admin and images

Comment: Do you mean `/admin/images` or `/admin` and `/images` separately?

Comment: /admin and /images separately

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?(index.html)?$ categories.php?prefix=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite all url unless a real folder or file is opened.